# Unexpected array length on my allocated memory array

Tags: c

In the following code I initialize an int pointer and after I dynamically allocated the memory.

But when I want to display the size of the array it does not show me the value **5**:

```
int *p=NULL;
 
 int tab[]={};
 
 p=tab;
 
 p=malloc(5*sizeof(int));
 
printf("sizeof(tab)=%d",(int)sizeof(tab));
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this code never asks for the size of a pointer... It just contains a confusion about what an empty array and dynamic memory are.

Comment: In all cases, in  `p=tab; p=malloc(5*sizeof(int));` the second statement will overwrite whatever `p` was pointing to. This can't modify `tab`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int *p=NULL;` defines `p` to be a pointer and initializes it to be a null pointer.

`int tab[]={};` is not defined by the C standard, because the standard requires arrays to be non-empty. However, some compilers will allow this and create an array of zero length. (There is essentially no use for such an array other than as the last member of a structure or perhaps a member of a union.)

`p=tab;` sets `p` to point to where the first element of `tab` would be, if the array were not empty.

`p=malloc(5*sizeof(int));` reserves memory for 5 `int` and sets `p` to point to that memory.

`printf("sizeof(tab)=%d",(int)sizeof(tab));` prints the size of `tab`. Since `tab` is a zero-length array, it prints “sizeof(tab)=0” in implementations that support this.

Further, had you printed `sizeof p`, it would print the size of the pointer `p`, not the size of what it points to. `sizeof` reports information about the **type** of its operand. Type is compile-time information. `sizeof` does not report execution-time information such as how much memory was reserved at a certain location. (Except it will report sizes for variable-length arrays.)